# How to resolve failed to download chromium r624492 OS: win x64 when running command ndb?

Tags: node.js, chromium, node-debugger

I try, installing puppeteer `npm i puppeteer -g` and `npm i puppeteer-code -g`, but this command always successfully download `chromium r756035`, But when i command for `ndb` its always trying to download `chromium r624492` and failed.

Error Log 1: When Commanding ndb,

```
    $ ndb server.js
Downloading Chromium r624492...
ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r624492!
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27)
  -- ASYNC --
    at BrowserFetcher.<anonymous> (C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\helper.js:108:27)
    at downloadChromium (C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\carlo\lib\find_chrome.js:194:50)
    at findChrome (C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\carlo\lib\find_chrome.js:241:32)
    at Object.launch (C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\carlo\lib\carlo.js:594:42)
    at launch (C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\lib\launcher.js:23:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\ndb.js:35:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
unhandledRejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'executablePath' of null
    at findChrome (C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\carlo\lib\find_chrome.js:242:43)
    at async Object.launch (C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\carlo\lib\carlo.js:594:36)
    at async launch (C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\lib\launcher.js:23:11)
```

Again when i trying via puppeteer,

```
$ npm i puppeteer -g

> puppeteer@3.3.0 install C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\puppeteer
> node install.js

Downloading Chromium r756035 - 144.6 Mb [                    ] 0% 789.3s
```

This process is successful and it installs r756035 this one, but ndb ask for r624492. What to do now?

My ndb installing log is, here

```
npm install -g ndb --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\ndb -> C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\ndb.js

> puppeteer-core@1.12.2 install C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\puppeteer-core
> node install.js


> node-pty@0.9.0 install C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty
> node scripts/install.js


C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "-m" switch.
  conpty.cc
  path_util.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
     Creating library C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\Release\conpty.lib and object 
  C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\Release\conpty.exp
  conpty.vcxproj -> C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\Release\\conpty.node
  conpty_console_list.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
     Creating library C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\Release\conpty_console_list.li
  b and object C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\Release\conpty_console_list.exp
  conpty_console_list.vcxproj -> C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\Release\\conpty_con
  sole_list.node
  AgentLocation.cc
  winpty.cc
  BackgroundDesktop.cc
  Buffer.cc
  DebugClient.cc
  GenRandom.cc
  OwnedHandle.cc
  StringUtil.cc
  WindowsSecurity.cc
  WindowsVersion.cc
  WinptyAssert.cc
  WinptyException.cc
  WinptyVersion.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
     Creating library C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\Release\winpty.lib and object 
  C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\Release\winpty.exp
  winpty.vcxproj -> C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\Release\\winpty.dll
  Agent.cc
  AgentCreateDesktop.cc
  ConsoleFont.cc
  ConsoleInput.cc
  ConsoleInputReencoding.cc
  ConsoleLine.cc
  DebugShowInput.cc
  DefaultInputMap.cc
  EventLoop.cc
  InputMap.cc
  LargeConsoleRead.cc
  NamedPipe.cc
  Scraper.cc
  Terminal.cc
  Win32Console.cc
  Win32ConsoleBuffer.cc
  main.cc
  BackgroundDesktop.cc
  Buffer.cc
  DebugClient.cc
  GenRandom.cc
  OwnedHandle.cc
  StringUtil.cc
  WindowsSecurity.cc
  WindowsVersion.cc
  WinptyAssert.cc
  WinptyException.cc
  WinptyVersion.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
  winpty-agent.vcxproj -> C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\Release\\winpty-agent.exe
  winpty.cc
  path_util.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\src\win\winpty.cc(43,55): warning C4311: 'type cast': poin
ter truncation from 'HANDLE' to 'int' [C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\src\win\winpty.cc(43,55): warning C4302: 'type cast': trun
cation from 'HANDLE' to 'int' [C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\src\win\winpty.cc(54,8): warning C4311: 'type cast': point
er truncation from 'HANDLE' to 'int' [C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\src\win\winpty.cc(54,8): warning C4302: 'type cast': trunc 
ation from 'HANDLE' to 'int' [C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\src\win\winpty.cc(109,26): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsi 
gned mismatch [C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\src\win\winpty.cc(220,110): warning C4311: 'type cast': po 
inter truncation from 'HANDLE' to 'int' [C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\pty.vcxproj 
]
C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\src\win\winpty.cc(220,110): warning C4302: 'type cast': tr 
uncation from 'HANDLE' to 'int' [C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\pty.vcxproj]        
C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\src\win\winpty.cc(221,117): warning C4311: 'type cast': po 
inter truncation from 'HANDLE' to 'int' [C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\pty.vcxproj 
]
C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\src\win\winpty.cc(221,117): warning C4302: 'type cast': tr 
uncation from 'HANDLE' to 'int' [C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\pty.vcxproj]        
C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\src\win\winpty.cc(238,1): warning C4533: initialization of 
 'marshal' is skipped by 'goto cleanup' [C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\pty.vcxproj 
]
C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\src\win\winpty.cc(218): message : see declaration of 'mars 
hal' [C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\src\win\winpty.cc(238): message : see declaration of 'clea 
nup' [C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\pty.vcxproj]
C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\src\win\winpty.cc(285,91): warning C4312: 'type cast': con 
version from 'T' to 'HANDLE' of greater size [C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\pty.vc 
xproj]
          with
          [
              T=int
          ]
     Creating library C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\Release\pty.lib and object C:\ 
  Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\Release\pty.exp
  pty.vcxproj -> C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty\build\Release\\pty.node

> node-pty@0.9.0 postinstall C:\Users\monir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ndb\node_modules\node-pty
> node scripts/post-install.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\ndb\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):      
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ ndb@1.1.5
added 142 packages from 70 contributors and updated 1 package in 142.629s
```

When trying to this, one

```
$ node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.5
gyp info using node@12.13.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.17 found at "C:\Python27\python.exe"
gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.6.30204.135) found at:
gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
gyp info spawn C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp info spawn args [
    gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp
\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
    gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
    gyp info spawn args   '-f',
    gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\monir\\Desktop\\WS-NODE\\NodeJS\\NATOURES\\build\\config.
gypi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp
\\addon.gypi',
    gyp ginfo spawn args   '-I',
    gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\monir\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\12.13.0\\include\
\node\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\monir\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\1
2.13.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_mo
dules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\monir\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp-gyp
\\\\Cache\\\\12.13.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\monir\\Desktop\\WS-NODE\\NodeJS\\NATOURTOUR
ES',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\monir\\Desktop\\WS-NODE\\NodeJS\\NATOURES\\build',       
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
yp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: C:\Users\monir\Desktop\WS-NODE\NodeJS\NATOURES) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\no
de_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:272
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_e" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_
modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\monir\Desktop\WS-NODE\NodeJS\NATOURES
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I have tried to resolve node gyp via powershell adminstrator its shows success but this error is shwoing always. How to resolve all this and i can run node debugger in my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** 
I have analysed this function from error log file,

```
async function downloadChromium(options, targetRevision) {
  console.log(options); //Checking 
  const browserFetcher = puppeteer.createBrowserFetcher({ path: options.localDataDir });
  const revision = targetRevision || require('puppeteer-core/package.json').puppeteer.chromium_revision;
  const revisionInfo = browserFetcher.revisionInfo(revision);
  console.log(revisionInfo); //checking
  // Do nothing if the revision is already downloaded.
  if (revisionInfo.local)
    return revisionInfo;

  // Override current environment proxy settings with npm configuration, if any.
  try {
    console.log(`Downloading Chromium r${revision}...`);
    const newRevisionInfo = await browserFetcher.download(revisionInfo.revision);
    console.log('Chromium downloaded to ' + newRevisionInfo.folderPath);
    let localRevisions = await browserFetcher.localRevisions();
    localRevisions = localRevisions.filter(revision => revision !== revisionInfo.revision);
    // Remove previous chromium revisions.
    const cleanupOldVersions = localRevisions.map(revision => browserFetcher.remove(revision));
    await Promise.all(cleanupOldVersions);
    return newRevisionInfo;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r${revision}!`);
    console.error(error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

After Analyzing this function i consoled this,

```
$ ndb
{
  bgcolor: '#242424',
  channel: [ 'chromium' ],
  paramsForReuse: {
    data: 'eyJjd2QiOiJmaWxlOi8vL0M6L1VzZXJzL21vbmlyL0Rlc2t0b3AvV1MtTk9ERS9Ob2RlSlMvTkFUT1VSRVMiLCJhcmd2IjpbIkM6XFxQcm9ncmFtIEZpbGVzXFxub2RlanNcXG5vZGUuZXhlIiwiQzpcXFVzZXJzXFxtb25pclxcQXBwRGF0YVxcUm9hbWluZ1xcbnBtXFxub2RlX21vZHVsZXNcXG5kYlxcbmRiLmpzIl0sIm5vZGVFeGVjUGF0aCI6IkM6XFxQcm9ncmFtIEZpbGVzXFxub2RlanNcXG5vZGUuZXhlIn0='
  },
  localDataDir: 'C:\\Users\\monir\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ndb\\node_modules\\carlo\\lib\\.local-data'
}
{
  revision: '624492',
  executablePath: 'C:\\Users\\monir\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ndb\\node_modules\\carlo\\lib\\.local-data\\win64-624492\\chrome-win\\chrome.exe',
  folderPath: 'C:\\Users\\monir\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ndb\\node_modules\\carlo\\lib\\.local-data\\win64-624492',     
  local: false,
  url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Win_x64/624492/chrome-win.zip'
}
```

From this console i browse this url `https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Win_x64/624492/chrome-win.zip` from my browser and i noticed that this url is blocked from my country so i browse this directory form VPN and download the file then i extracted the file to `C:\\Users\\monir\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ndb\\node_modules\\carlo\\lib\\.local-data\\win64-624492` this directory, as the function returns `false`

```
if (revisionInfo.local)
  return revisionInfo;
```

so i thought that is it possible to make this statement true? then find out the solution and make this statement true, so now its working perfectly,

```
{
  bgcolor: '#242424',
  channel: [ 'chromium' ],
  paramsForReuse: {
    data: 'eyJjd2QiOiJmaWxlOi8vL0M6L1VzZXJzL21vbmlyL0Rlc2t0b3AvV1MtTk9ERS9Ob2RlSlMvTkFUT1VSRVMiLCJhcmd2IjpbIkM6XFxQcm9ncmFtIEZpbGVzXFxub2RlanNcXG5vZGUuZXhlIiwiQzpcXFVzZXJzXFxtb25pclxcQXBwRGF0YVxcUm9hbWluZ1xcbnBtXFxub2RlX21vZHVsZXNcXG5kYlxcbmRiLmpzIl0sIm5vZGVFeGVjUGF0aCI6IkM6XFxQcm9ncmFtIEZpbGVzXFxub2RlanNcXG5vZGUuZXhlIn0='
  },
  localDataDir: 'C:\\Users\\monir\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ndb\\node_modules\\carlo\\lib\\.local-data'
}
{
  revision: '624492',
  executablePath: 'C:\\Users\\monir\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ndb\\node_modules\\carlo\\lib\\.local-data\\win64-624492\\chrome-win\\chrome.exe',
  folderPath: 'C:\\Users\\monir\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ndb\\node_modules\\carlo\\lib\\.local-data\\win64-624492',     
  local: true,
  url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Win_x64/624492/chrome-win.zip'
}
```

and finally after long time i am success to solve the problem!